# Finding item and dependent set of items from the same mysql table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I store items and the time where they are relevant. For this question the following columns are relevant:

```
 CREATE TABLE my_items 
 (
   id INTEGER,
   category INTEGER,
   t DOUBLE
  );
```

I want to select all items from a specific category (e.g. 1) and the sets of items that have a time within +- 5 (seconds) from these items.

I will probably do this with two types of queries in a script:

```
 SELECT id,t from my_items where category=1;
```

then loop over the result set, using each result row's time as t_q1, and do a separate query:

```
 SELECT id from my_items where t >= t_q1-5 AND t <= t_q1+5;
```

How can I do this in one query?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join. Take your subquery that selects all category 1 items, and join it with the original table on the condition that the time is within +/- five. It's possible that duplicate rows are returned, so you can group by id to avoid that:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
JOIN (SELECT id, timeCol FROM myTable WHERE category = 1) t1 
   ON t.timeCol BETWEEN (t1.timeCol - 5) AND (t1.timeCol + 5)
   OR t.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

I added the `OR t.id = t1.id` to make sure that the rows of category 1 are still included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query with all you criteria if there is only one table

`SELECT id,t from my_items where category=1 AND t >= t_q1-5 AND t <= t_q1+5;`

If there is two tables, use a right join on the timestamps table for performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  id
from    my_items i, 
        (select min(t) min_t, max(t) max_t from my_items where category=1) i2
where   i.category = 1 or
        i.t between i2.min_t-5 and i2.max_t+5
```